# Limiting the Number of Attendees

Tags: 2013, workflow, development, custom-list

Created a list that keep tracks of people signing up for a class.  Is there a way I can set a custom list that will not allow anyone to be able to sign-up if it reaches a certain number of people.  I was thinking to adding  calculated column that will when it reaches a number, but don't know how to set limits or lock from anyone signup if it reaches that number.  Does anyone know how or if this can be done in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 2013 CSR and the [OnPreRender function](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views) is one, and maybe even the best way of skinning this cat.
You will have to read the whole list and then not display the Form but a message.

But you can do without CSR and make SharePoint do half the work for you.

A quick and easy ductape patch from the olden days is to hide the NewForm contents.

- On the NewForm.aspx page add a ListView WebPart, make it list **all** your items
  change the WebPart Layouts Properties Zone-Index to 1 to make it display **below** the NewForm
- Add another WebPart, use a Content Editor WebPart with the contents:

  ```
  SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', null, function(){//execute after pageload
      var items = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-itmhover');//all displayed listitems
      console && console.info('There are ',items.length,'in this list');
      if (items.length > 10) {//maximum number of items
          var form = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-formtable')[0];//new form
          GetAncestor(form,'DIV').innerHTML = '<h1>Numbers of records has exceeded the permitted limit: '+items.length+'</h1>';
      } else {//optional: hide the View with all the items
          var itemlist=items[0];//first item
          GetAncestor(itemlist,'DIV').style.display='none';
      }
  });
  ```

*Note: you have to wrap this in a < script>< / script> tag, StackOverflow doesn't display it properly*

Tip: place the javascript in a separate file and link the Content Editor Web Part to it.. makes it easier to edit... you still have to include the < script> tag!!

[image]

Comment: Thank you Danny.  I followed the steps, but its not throwing out the message once the item list reaches over 10 items.  I am missing something?

Comment: I have added 1 line. Press F12 (Developer Tools) and check the Console Tab for the output (some JavaScript skills are required to debug whats not making it work for you)

Comment: Thanks Danny.  I noticed that you added 1 line.  I most of chosen an incorrect tag.  I will double check.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a workflow with SharePoint Designer or Visio(and import it in SP Designer) where you should be able to set the workflow to wait until you reach the number of records that you want. After that, you continue the workflow by blocking access to that list. 
**Im not sure that you can do it only by Visio or SP Designer. Im affraid that you must create the workflow with powershell, but it can be done.**